# How to send Woocommerce Customer Details (Name, Email and Phone Number) to Admin upon signup

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email, user-registration, wp-register-script

**Use case:**

I want to send an email notification to the admin or the sales staff whenever someone signup as customer on my Woocommerce Shop.

Details I want to include: Name, Phone Number, Email Address.
I'm already taking phone number while registration as **billing_phone**

**Issue**

The snippet mentioned below sends email address only. Not the NAME or the Phone Number.

I want send the Phone number, email and name to the any given email of the staff. Can you help me with this?

```
    function so174837_registration_email_alert( $user_id ) {
    $user    = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $email   = $user->user_email;
      $name   = $user->user_email;
    $phone = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );
    $message = $name.''.$email .' - ' .$phone. 'has registered to your website.';
    $subject1= $name. ' - '.$phone .'just signed up. Call him.';
    wp_mail( 'xxy@gmail.com', $subject1, $message );
}add_action('user_register', 'so174837_registration_email_alert');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this: **$name = $user->user_email;** to this:

```
$name = $user->first_name;
```

And this: **$phone = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );** to this:

```
$phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );
```

Did it work for you? Let me know! =)

Comment: Thanks for answering this but it did not work. I just tested it.